# Offline Map-Matching freezes

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, map-matching

I am using Offline Map-Matching and the process always freezes at the same time (8% of calculating transition probabilities, as shown on the image):

[image]

I get no messages and have no idea what could be wrong.

Tried the following:

-using a metric CRS

-using only 14 points with 4 sec intervals

-using different maximum search distances (up to 350 m)

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I asked the same question and received an answer here:

https://github.com/jagodki/Offline-MapMatching/issues/23

However, could not test it properly as decided to use another approach.